# ORDS installation on TOMCAT 9

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, tomcat9

I am new to this job.
- First I have installed Apache tomcat with the port 8085 in Windows Server 2016. (Let's name this as SVR1) Then I have installed ORDS on tomcat Apache as the web listener.
 - I could access apex application as ADMIN with the following URL from SVR1. http://localhost:8085/ords/

But my problem is when i change this URL to http://SVR1:8085/ords/ the it doesn't give me the apex application login page as earlier.
Please help me and guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: I'am quite new too but I'm strugling with the same stack. I have not yet a solution but a couple of questions: what happen if you try the URL http://SVR1:8085 from your windows server or from a different pc? Tomcat manager appears? Is it possible that the server do not understand that SVR1 is the same than localhost?